# Generic list sorting. At least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, sorting, generic-list

i have a list of my g class

```
Public Class g
    Public x as Decimal
    Public y As Decimal
End Class

Dim MyQuery As List(Of g) = ...
```

which i try to sort like

```
Dim sorted As List(Of g) = MyQuery.OrderBy(Function(x) x.y).ThenBy(Function(x) x.x).ToList()
```

Unfortunately i get the following error

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

What am i doing wrong here? 
When i try to sort by one property i get no errors

`Dim sorted As List(Of g) = MyQuery.OrderBy(Function(x) x.y).ToList()`

Comment: Please don't obfuscate your code. Provide meaningful samples, for instance, what is `Function(x) x.x`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for your comment just updated

Comment: This should work (assuming `x` / `y` are in fact `decimal`). Maybe try using a different variable name for the `ThenBy` query i.e. `ThenBy(function(y) y.y)` - not really sure if it will make a difference but they could be clashing.

Comment: I just tested it, it works. Please provide an example that actually reproduces your error... Most likely you aren't using decimal but other types and those types in turn don't implement `IComparable`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Do you mind posting this as an answer? That was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided in your question works as is. Your original code most likely doesn't use `decimal` for the properties but some other type that doesn't implement `IComparable`, resulting in the exception you get.